# Cant connect to localhost database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

so Im trying to connect to a localhost database. Im probably not creating the user properly. I created the user in phpmyadmin>User accounts with the following info:

- User name: myUsername
- Host name: localhost (replaced the "%" that was by default)
- Password: myPassword
- Authentication Plugin: Native MySQL Authentication (the only option)

And here's my code:

```
Try 
{ 
$Server = "localhost"
$Database = "myDatabase"
$uid ="myUsername"
$pwd = "myPassword"
$SQLConnection = New-ObjectSystem.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection 
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$Server;database=$Database;Integrated Security=True" 
$SQLConnection.Open() 
} 
catch 
{ 
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Failed to connect SQL Server:")  
}
```

In line 8 I also tried

```
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$Server;database=$Database;Integrated Security=False;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd"
```

and..

```
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$Server;database=$Database;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd"
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Yet it's hard to tell what's wrong. Could be just typo in "New-ObjectSystem.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection", it's missing spacing like so "New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection".

Comment: Error message pls.

Comment: The error is: Exception calling "open" with "0" argument(s)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have mentioned **MySql** in the fourth point where as your connection object represents MSSQL.

If you are connecting to ***MSSQL***, then you made a syntactical error in declaration of connection string. Below mentioned:

**Instead Of this:**

```
$Server = "localhost"
$Database = "myDatabase"
$uid ="myUsername"
$pwd = "myPassword"
$SQLConnection = New-ObjectSystem.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection 
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$Server;database=$Database;Integrated Security=True" 
$SQLConnection.Open()
```

Do this:

```
$Server = "localhost"
$Database = "myDatabase"
$uid ="myUsername"
$pwd = "myPassword"
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection 
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString ="server=$Server;uid=$uid; pwd=$pwd;database=$Database;Integrated Security=False" 
$SQLConnection.Open()
```

If you are using **Mysql**,you have to install connector and then use like this:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$connectionString = "server=$server;uid=$uid;pwd=$pwd;database=$database;"
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$sql = "show tables"
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sql, $connection)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$recordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($table)
echo $table
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. If anyone needs it in the future: [here's](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/powershell/querying-mysql-from-powershell) another useful resource for installing connector and connecting to mysql using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a MSSQL Server instead of a MySQL.
Your connection should be initialized like this:

```
$SQLConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
```